# NodeJs: TypeError: require (…) no es una función

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Intenté lanzar un chatbot que se hizo con botkit y javascript. Sin embargo obtenía un `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app\components\express_webserver.js:22
      require("./express_middleware/" + file)(webserver, controller);
                                             ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app\components\express_webserver.js:22:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app\components\express_webserver.js:21:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\PACO\Code 19-04-03\app\bot.js:62:72)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
```

No sé si el error proviene de una dependencia circular. En cualquier caso, no puedo ser exportado a un módulo `./App/route` porque no hay ninguno.

## express_webserver.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var debug = require("debug")("botkit:webserver");

module.exports = function(controller, bot) {
  var webserver = express();
  webserver.use(bodyParser.json());
  webserver.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  webserver.use((req, res, next) => {
    // res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/ https://www.facebook.com/');
    // res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/");
    // res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://l.facebook.com/');
    next();
  });

  // import express middlewares that are present in /components/express_middleware
  var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "express_middleware");
  require("fs")
    .readdirSync(normalizedPath)
    .forEach(function(file) {
      require("./express_middleware/" + file)(webserver, controller);
    });

  webserver.use(express.static("build"));
  webserver.use(express.static('public'));

  webserver.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, null, function() {
    debug(
      "Express webserver configured and listening at http://localhost:" +
        process.env.PORT || 3000
    );
  });

  // import all the pre-defined routes that are present in /components/routes
  var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "routes");
  require("fs")
    .readdirSync(normalizedPath)
    .forEach(function(file) {
      require("./routes/" + file)(webserver, controller);
    });

  controller.webserver = webserver;

  return webserver;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:

```
.forEach(function(file) {
  require("./express_middleware/" + file)(webserver, controller);
});
```

Si lo escribes así:

```
.forEach(function(file) {
  const fn = require("./express_middleware/" + file)
  fn(webserver, controller);
});
```

Podrás ver que en una de las veces `fn` no es una función (quizá sea `undefined`, si no se ha encontrado el fichero), con lo que la posterior llamada falla. Una solución sería hacer algo como:

```
.forEach(function(file) {
  const fn = require(`./express_middleware/${file}`);
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn(webserver, controller);
  } else {
    console.log(`fn no es una función al importar ./express_middleware/${file}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sin embargo, ¿No falta un punto y coma?. Además, Tengo el error TypeError: fn no es una función. Que debo hacer ?

Comment: El punto y coma falta si sigues buenas costumbres... aunque en JS es opcional. Ahora te edito la respuesta

Comment: Si, obtengo `fn it is not a function when importing ./express_middleware/Icon_`. Entonces sé que falta: es un archivo llamado `Icon`, no ?

Comment: Parece que `Icon_`

Comment: Parece que `Icon_` que ?

Comment: Parece que el fichero que falta tiene el nombre `Icon_`, con el *guión bajo* incluído

Comment: Es extraño. Hay un que se llama como esto. Está absolutamente vacío.